# MySql Insert Query returns 2 records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are total 3 tables in my database namely `village`,`branch`,`country`.

First of all I insert village from the form using following query:

```
$intTalukaId = $_POST['selCenter'];
$strVillageName = $_POST['villagename'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO Villages VALUES( '','$strVillageName','$intTalukaId')";
```

It inserted village successfully.

Then I want latest insert village id that is to be used in next query where I `select max( village_id) from villages`. It returns maximum value but in database it insert two values at the same time.

For example: current in village table `village_id` is 30 after this query executes it shows 31 and 32 with same  record.

Can anyone help why this happen ?

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code?

Comment: how you are inserting show the code

Comment: Rather than selecting the MAX village id, better to use mysqli_insert_id to get the id of the latest inserted record - http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php . With your method of 2 villages are being inserted by different scripts simultaneously you might not get the village_id that your script just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pdo, use `[PDO::lastInsertId.][1]`

if you are using mysqli, use `[mysqli::$insert_id][2].`

if you are using mysql, just stop using it.

Good luck with your application :)

Answer (score 0):

If your village_id is an auto- increment key, you might be looking for [**last_insert_id()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).
It is session specific. So no worry. [These](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/last_insert_id/) [links](http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=56) are worth good for a read.